# For loop inside a for loop?

Tags: for-loop, octave

I wish to write a code that would give me a [5x5] matrix containing values of "ec" for each step. But here I can only return its last value. Could you please help me?

Thanks for your interest

```
R = [0.13, 0.131, 0.132, 0.133, 0.134];
k = [1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3];
a = 3*60*6/1000;
for i=R
ec = 30 * (i*a + i*a*k/100)
endfor
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want something like

```
ec = zeros(5);
R = [0.13, 0.131, 0.132, 0.133, 0.134];
k = [1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3];
a = 3*60*6/1000;
for i_=1:length(R)
    for j_=1:length(k)
        ec(i_,j_) = 30 * (R(i_)*a + R(i_)*a*k(j_)/100);
    end
end
```

unless I'm mistaken about your question.  This should return a 5x5 matrix `ec`.

A note about for loops: you should avoid using `i` as a counter, because this is predefined as equal to sqrt(-1), and if you reassign it there can be problems.  Adding an underscore avoids this problem.